# How to stop AJAX calls if there's an error on a field with a keyup trigger

Tags: ajax, firefox, jquery, keyup

I have this jquery ajax call that is trigger on `keyup`. It has error handling which (with Firefox for e.g.) is triggered multiples times if the user enters keystrokes fast. Is there a quick way to stop multiple alert windows to be shown?

```
$('input[name$="_LOC"]').keyup(function(){

    if ($(this).val().length >=4){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'red.asp?q='+$(this).val(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                    [...]   
            },
            success: function(data) {
                [...]
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Oops!")
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart a timer each time the onkeyup is triggered, this means the event only happens when the user has finished typing (or, at least, paused for a second or whatever).

Use `timer = setTimeout(yourFunction, yourDelay);`

To rest the timer user `clearInterval(timer)` and start the setTimeout again.

```
var typing = false;
var timer;

$('input[name$="_LOC"]').keyup(function(){
 if(typing) {
   clearInterval(timer);

 }
timer = setTimeout(sendAjax, 500, [this]);
 typing=true;
});

function sendAjax(element) 
{
    if ($(element).val().length >=4){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'red.asp?q='+$(element).val(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                    [...]   
            },
            success: function(data) {
                [...]
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Oops!")
            }
        }); 
    typing = false;   
   }
```

Here's JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/X8US5/, you'll need your browsers console.log viewer ready to see stuff (otherwise edit the console.logs to be alerts though they interrupt JS so times will be off)

**Edit:**
IE9 compatible (hack) version http://jsfiddle.net/5ndM5/1/
Tried to find a jQuery alternative but none it seems. 
THe overriding the function alternative is good if you don't want the global var, but if you only plan to use this code on one form then the global is acceptable (JS code is usually rife with them by accident anyway)

Comment: have problems passing `element` to sendAjax function in IE; it's undefined?

Comment: It gets passed to the function via setTimeout's 3rd argument, without seeing code.. not much else I can say sorry. try console.logging it before each of your setTimeout ccalls (along with a string) see where it goes missing.

Comment: A little harsh un-accepting the answer because your implementation doesn't work yet..

Comment: what can I say, it doesn't work in your JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X8US5/1/ console.log("ajax="+element) shows element as undefined, or am i getting it wrong?

Comment: I get `ajax=[object HTMLInputElement]"`

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm Chrome, works in Firefox too.

Comment: Chrome and FF work. I have the issue in IE only. On more than 1 computer.. really strange

Comment: Apparently IE doesn't approve of third argument, there is a workaround on this site: http://webreflection.blogspot.de/2011/05/settimeout-and-setinterval-with-extra.html, an alternative is to make the "element" global and when any keyUp gets hit it overwrites that global var with the current element. Would you like me to modify the fiddle for that?

Comment: thanks. I was looking at that article and clearly its author is at a higher flight level than me