# javascript delay after onkeup

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

So referencing this:
[How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay)

I came up with the following code. But it does nothing... Any suggestions?

I am trying to get the setTimeout to cancel if the user types something further, so that multiple alerts don't happen, only one when the user finally 'stops' (hopefully).

Thanks!!

```
var t = 0;  
$('input').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(alert($('input').val()),1000);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387958/how-to-stop-ajax-calls-if-theres-an-error-on-a-field-with-a-keyup-trigger/13388050#13388050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
t = setTimeout(alert($('input').val()),1000);
```

with

```
t = setTimeout(function(){alert($('input').val())},1000);
```

You were passing the value of the input to setTimeout, while [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) needs a function (or a string it can evaluate as code) as first argument.

And replace the last line with `});` so that the code compiles.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/LupJx/)

Comment: How strange! Can you tell me why mine is not working? http://jsfiddle.net/x9774/15/

Comment: @phileaton It doesn't compile because last line should be });

Comment: @Selosindis Obviously. But I suppose the real world case would have a more interesting selector, probably ID based. There would be no interest in echoing **all** inputs of the page !

Comment: Absolutely, but it seems pertinent as part of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the .val() of a list of elements. $('input') is selecting *all* inputs on the screen and will only ever give the value of the first one in the list.

This code should work for all inputs, but only run the timeout on the one that fired the event.

```
var t = 0;  
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var that = this;

    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        alert($(that).val());
    }, 1000);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Well, jQuery it will get the val of the *first one*, but that's often not what's intended.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent confusion on several different inputs, use `this` reference, keep timeout in `data()`:

```
var out = $('#out');
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout($this.data('timeout'));
    $this.data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
        out.append($('<div>').text(($this.attr('id') + ': ' + $this.val())));
    }, 1000));
});​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/YAwXG/)